# Python Audio Tools installation problem

Tags: python, linux, audio, makefile, installation

I've a problem with installing Python Audio Tools. I downloaded the latest package (2.17) from their site, and when I run `make install` as root (as instructed by INSTALL file), I get this:

```
mateusz@mateusz-laptop:~/downloads/audiotools-2.17$ sudo make install
python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'audiotools.cdio' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c src/cdiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/src/cdiomodule.o
In file included from src/cdiomodule.c:1:
src/cdiomodule.h:1:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
src/cdiomodule.h:2:23: error: cdio/cdda.h: No such file or directory
src/cdiomodule.h:3:27: error: cdio/paranoia.h: No such file or directory
In file included from src/cdiomodule.c:1:
src/cdiomodule.h:14: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘PyObject_HEAD’
src/cdiomodule.h:23: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.h:27: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘PyObject’
src/cdiomodule.h:27: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘PyObject’
src/cdiomodule.h:29: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.h:32: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.h:35: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.h:38: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.h:41: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.h:44: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.h:47: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.h:50: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.h:53: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.h:56: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.h:59: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.h:63: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘paranoia_cb_mode_t’
src/cdiomodule.h:65: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.h:68: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘CDDA_methods’
src/cdiomodule.h:96: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘PyObject_HEAD’
src/cdiomodule.h:104: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.h:108: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘PyObject’
src/cdiomodule.h:108: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘PyObject’
src/cdiomodule.h:113: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.h:116: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.h:119: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.h:122: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.h:125: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.h:128: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.h:131: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.h:134: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.h:137: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.h:141: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘CDImage_methods’
src/cdiomodule.h:165: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘cdioMethods’
src/cdiomodule.h:177: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘cdio_CDDAType’
src/cdiomodule.h:219: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘cdio_CDImageType’
In file included from src/cdiomodule.c:2:
/usr/include/cdio/cd_types.h:142: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘uint8_t’
/usr/include/cdio/cd_types.h:151: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘cdio_guess_cd_type’
In file included from src/cdiomodule.c:3:
/usr/include/cdio/audio.h:74: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘cdio_audio_get_volume’
/usr/include/cdio/audio.h:87: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘cdio_audio_pause’
/usr/include/cdio/audio.h:96: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘cdio_audio_play_msf’
/usr/include/cdio/audio.h:106: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘cdio_audio_play_track_index’
/usr/include/cdio/audio.h:115: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘cdio_audio_read_subchannel’
/usr/include/cdio/audio.h:124: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘cdio_audio_resume’
/usr/include/cdio/audio.h:133: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘cdio_audio_set_volume’
/usr/include/cdio/audio.h:142: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘cdio_audio_stop’
In file included from src/cdiomodule.c:4:
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:112: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:120: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:126: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:136: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:142: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:147: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:153: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:163: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:169: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:183: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:197: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:208: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:219: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:233: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:245: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:251: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/cdio/track.h:262: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from src/cdiomodule.c:6:
src/pcm.h:44: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘PyObject_HEAD’
src/pcm.h:62: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:65: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘PyObject’
src/pcm.h:65: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘PyObject’
src/pcm.h:72: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:76: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:78: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:81: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:84: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:90: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:96: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:99: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:102: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:105: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:108: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:111: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:114: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:117: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:120: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:123: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:126: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:135: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘PyObject_HEAD’
src/pcm.h:152: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:156: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘PyObject’
src/pcm.h:156: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘PyObject’
src/pcm.h:159: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:161: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:167: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:170: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:176: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:179: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:182: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:185: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:188: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:191: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:194: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/pcm.h:197: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.c:31: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.c: In function ‘initcdio’:
src/cdiomodule.c:36: error: ‘PyObject’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/cdiomodule.c:36: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
src/cdiomodule.c:36: error: for each function it appears in.)
src/cdiomodule.c:36: error: ‘m’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/cdiomodule.c:38: error: ‘cdio_CDDAType’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/cdiomodule.c:38: error: ‘PyType_GenericNew’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/cdiomodule.c:39: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyType_Ready’
src/cdiomodule.c:42: error: ‘cdio_CDImageType’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/cdiomodule.c:46: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘Py_InitModule3’
src/cdiomodule.c:46: error: ‘cdioMethods’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/cdiomodule.c:49: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘Py_INCREF’
src/cdiomodule.c:50: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyModule_AddObject’
src/cdiomodule.c:50: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
src/cdiomodule.c:53: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
src/cdiomodule.c:55: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyModule_AddIntConstant’
src/cdiomodule.c: In function ‘CDDA_dealloc’:
src/cdiomodule.c:70: error: ‘cdio_CDDAObject’ has no member named ‘paranoia’
src/cdiomodule.c:71: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘cdio_paranoia_free’
src/cdiomodule.c:71: error: ‘cdio_CDDAObject’ has no member named ‘paranoia’
src/cdiomodule.c:72: error: ‘cdio_CDDAObject’ has no member named ‘cdrom_drive’
src/cdiomodule.c:73: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘cdio_cddap_close’
src/cdiomodule.c:73: error: ‘cdio_CDDAObject’ has no member named ‘cdrom_drive’
src/cdiomodule.c:74: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘Py_XDECREF’
src/cdiomodule.c:74: error: ‘cdio_CDDAObject’ has no member named ‘pcm_module’
src/cdiomodule.c:76: error: ‘cdio_CDDAObject’ has no member named ‘ob_type’
src/cdiomodule.c:76: error: ‘PyObject’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/cdiomodule.c:76: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
src/cdiomodule.c: At top level:
src/cdiomodule.c:79: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.c:91: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘PyObject’
src/cdiomodule.c:91: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘PyObject’
src/cdiomodule.c: In function ‘CDDA_init’:
src/cdiomodule.c:95: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyArg_ParseTuple’
src/cdiomodule.c:95: error: ‘args’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/cdiomodule.c:98: error: ‘cdio_CDDAObject’ has no member named ‘pcm_module’
src/cdiomodule.c:98: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyImport_ImportModule’
src/cdiomodule.c:101: error: ‘cdio_CDDAObject’ has no member named ‘cdrom_drive’
src/cdiomodule.c:101: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘cdio_cddap_identify’
src/cdiomodule.c:102: error: ‘cdio_CDDAObject’ has no member named ‘cdrom_drive’
src/cdiomodule.c:103: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyErr_SetString’
src/cdiomodule.c:103: error: ‘PyExc_IOError’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/cdiomodule.c:108: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘cdio_cddap_open’
src/cdiomodule.c:108: error: ‘cdio_CDDAObject’ has no member named ‘cdrom_drive’
src/cdiomodule.c:114: error: ‘cdio_CDDAObject’ has no member named ‘paranoia’
src/cdiomodule.c:114: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘cdio_paranoia_init’
src/cdiomodule.c:114: error: ‘cdio_CDDAObject’ has no member named ‘cdrom_drive’
src/cdiomodule.c:115: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘paranoia_modeset’
src/cdiomodule.c:115: error: ‘cdio_CDDAObject’ has no member named ‘paranoia’
src/cdiomodule.c:116: error: ‘PARANOIA_MODE_FULL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/cdiomodule.c:116: error: ‘PARANOIA_MODE_NEVERSKIP’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/cdiomodule.c: At top level:
src/cdiomodule.c:121: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.c:131: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.c:148: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.c:189: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.c:237: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.c:243: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.c:249: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.c:262: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.c:278: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.c:292: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.c:314: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.c:328: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘PyObject’
src/cdiomodule.c:328: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘PyObject’
src/cdiomodule.c: In function ‘CDImage_init’:
src/cdiomodule.c:332: error: ‘args’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/cdiomodule.c:335: error: ‘cdio_CDImage’ has no member named ‘pcm_module’
src/cdiomodule.c:340: error: ‘cdio_CDImage’ has no member named ‘image’
src/cdiomodule.c:340: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘cdio_open_cue’
src/cdiomodule.c:343: error: ‘cdio_CDImage’ has no member named ‘image’
src/cdiomodule.c:343: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘cdio_open_bincue’
src/cdiomodule.c:346: error: ‘cdio_CDImage’ has no member named ‘image’
src/cdiomodule.c:346: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘cdio_open_cdrdao’
src/cdiomodule.c:349: error: ‘cdio_CDImage’ has no member named ‘image’
src/cdiomodule.c:349: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘cdio_open_nrg’
src/cdiomodule.c:352: error: ‘cdio_CDImage’ has no member named ‘image’
src/cdiomodule.c:356: error: ‘cdio_CDImage’ has no member named ‘image’
src/cdiomodule.c:357: error: ‘PyExc_ValueError’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/cdiomodule.c: In function ‘CDImage_dealloc’:
src/cdiomodule.c:366: error: ‘cdio_CDImage’ has no member named ‘image’
src/cdiomodule.c:367: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘cdio_destroy’
src/cdiomodule.c:367: error: ‘cdio_CDImage’ has no member named ‘image’
src/cdiomodule.c:369: error: ‘cdio_CDImage’ has no member named ‘pcm_module’
src/cdiomodule.c:370: error: ‘cdio_CDImage’ has no member named ‘ob_type’
src/cdiomodule.c:370: error: ‘PyObject’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/cdiomodule.c:370: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
src/cdiomodule.c: At top level:
src/cdiomodule.c:373: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.c:378: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.c:390: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.c:416: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.c:448: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.c:455: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.c:462: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.c:473: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.c:482: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.c:501: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/cdiomodule.c:523: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘paranoia_cb_mode_t’
src/cdiomodule.c: In function ‘read_sector_callback’:
src/cdiomodule.c:525: error: ‘PyObject’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/cdiomodule.c:525: error: ‘arglist’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/cdiomodule.c:56: error: ‘result’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/cdiomodule.c:528: error: ‘read_callback’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/cdiomodule.c:531: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘Py_BuildValue’
src/cdiomodule.c:531: error: ‘mode’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/cdiomodule.c:532: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘PyEval_CallObject’
src/cdiomodule.c:533: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘Py_DECREF’
src/cdiomodule.c: At top level:
src/cdiomodule.c:538: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

gcc is 4.5.5. I'm using Python 2.6.

Forgot to add, I have libcdio installed. Both -utils and -dev packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, the Audio Tools turned out to be something else I was looking for. That's what you get for not reading docs closely enough. :P

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED

I first commented out cdda.h inclusion, and got the same complain about cdio/paranoia.h.

My web searches brought up http://aspensmonster.com/tag/media/ which suggests:

> After installing the “libcdio-paranoia-dev” file, this error went away and VLC continued to compile.

So I installed the libcdio-paranoia-dev package and then I could compile and install.

Moreover, audiotools compiled again successfully after restoring initial cdiomodule.h and make clean.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

You'll also need the python-devel package. That's where the missing Python.h file is found.

Comment: I have python-dev and python2.6-dev installed (there are no python-devel packages).

Answer (score 1):

If you installed all dependencies, have already the error with `cdio/cdda.h`, use ArchLinux as your Linux distribution and you do not use the [AUR package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/audiotools/) you should replace two lines in the audiotools source:

```
sed 's/#include <cdio\/cdda.h>/#include <cdio\/paranoia\/cdda.h>/' -i src/cdiomodule.h
sed 's/#include <cdio\/paranoia.h>/#include <cdio\/paranoia\/paranoia.h>/' -i src/cdiomodule.h
```

Therefor you need the `libcdio-paranoia` ArchLinux package installed. After you replaced the two lines you can build audiotools (with `make install` or `python2 setup.py build && python2 setup.py install`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who (like me) stumbles over this from Google, I fixed it by linking python to python2.7 instead of python3.